# how to use terraform remote state when using a resource that is not yet created by terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a chicken and egg situation here.

I want to store the terraform state in azure blob storage but I want to use terraform to create the key vault first.

I can't specify an access key if the key vault store does not exist.

I have resorted to using bash to create the key vault store first but this is less than ideal.

Is there a way around this?

Could I use the terraform refresh command after I have created the backend store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's the problem of the possibility, not the chicken and egg problem.

First, if you want to store the state file in azure blob storage, you need first create storage before. When you create the storage, the access key is already existing.

Second, when you store the access key of the storage in a key vault, you need to have the access key before. I think here is the problem you think. But the access key is necessary before you create the Terraform files, although you storage the key in the key vault. You can see the steps in [Store Terraform state in Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/terraform/terraform-backend), no matter you store the access key in the key vault or not, get access key is at the very beginning of all the steps.

So what you think it's impossible. If you want to use the Azure storage to store the state, the right sequence is:

1. create an azure storage account and a container
2. get the access key and set it as an environment variable
3. create terraform files and use the storage account to store the state

Comment: I think you are right, I thought the terraform refresh command might magically change where the state is stored